# How do I add UserClaims to ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, membershipreboot

I've got a C# .NET project setup using Entity Framework, [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) and [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).

I'm looking at the database and I see a `UserClaims` table. Inside this table I've added a few claims using the MembershipReboot [`AddClaim`](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/f2201fc4a945b6fca6fdfb2d3ab6831f9029da78/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/AccountService/UserAccountService.cs#L2649) method.

The claims from the `UserClaims` table are somehow added to the `ClaimsPrincipal`. I can see this when I send a request to my `Controller`. In the controllers `ActionResult` method I have the following couple lines of code:

```
var claimsPrincipal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
if (claimsPrincipal != null)
{
    var userClaims = claimsPrincipal.Claims;
```

In this example `userClaims` will contain the claims from MembershipReboots `UserClaims` table.

In a similar fashion I'd like to add some additional claims to the `ClaimsPrincipal` without using the UserClaims table. The idea is that if a user is a member of a group then they will inherit claims which are associated with that group. I've created a separate table that I'm storing these group claims in - but I'm having trouble actually adding these claims to the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

I've been looking at the [`SamAuthenticationService`](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/master/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.WebHost/SamAuthenticationService.cs) in MembershipReboot however I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place.

Would someone more familiar with MembershipReboot and IdentityServer be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more digging I've discovered where the claims are gathered and added to the `ClaimsPrincipal` within MembershipReboot.

The `ClaimsPrincipal` is set within the [`Sign In` method in the `AuthenticationService`](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/f36d65d89e60b5a8838e1873c06aca33278bb1e4/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/Authentication/AuthenticationService.cs#L82-L99). The `SignIn` method does the following things before creating the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

1. Gathers Claims that MembershipReboot manages (including the claims in the `UserClaims` table).
2. Get's custom claims by calling [`UserAccountService.MapClaims`](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/master/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/AccountService/UserAccountService.cs#L3091-L3095)

The `UserAccountService.MapClaims` method executes a `MapClaimsFromAccount<TAccount>` command. It's at this point where you can actually register a handler with MembershipReboot to run a custom claims mapper. Your mapper will be executed and the claims you return will be added to the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

It took me a while to find this - but this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot/issues/11#issuecomment-68960680) helped a lot. I'll copy the code out below.

Essentially what you do is create a `CustomMapper` which implements an `ICommandHandler<MapClaimsFromAccount<CustomUserAccount>>`. Where `CustomUserAccount` is your own class that extends [`RelationalUserAccount`](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/f36d65d89e60b5a8838e1873c06aca33278bb1e4/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/Account/Relational/RelationalUserAccount.cs).

### Custom Claims Mapper

```
public class CustomClaimsMapper : ICommandHandler<MapClaimsFromAccount<CustomUserAccount>>
{
    public void Handle(MapClaimsFromAccount<CustomUserAccount> cmd)
    {
        cmd.MappedClaims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[]
        {
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, cmd.Account.FirstName),
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, cmd.Account.LastName),
        };
    }
}
```

This is the code you would use to map your own custom claims. The claims given above are just example. These claims can be whatever you need for your application.

### Registering the Mapper

```
public static MembershipRebootConfiguration<CustomUserAccount> config;
static MembershipRebootUserServiceFactory()
{
    config = new MembershipRebootConfiguration<CustomUserAccount>();

    //Add a handler for the Custom User Account Type
    config.AddCommandHandler(new CustomClaimsMapper());
}
```

This is where you would add a command handler for your custom mapper.

Now when the `ClaimsPrincipal` is created it will include any claims you return from your custom mapper.